How can I fetch fields and datatypes from elasticsearch?
Is there a query I can issue to elasticsearch to be able to fetch out fields with the following format:

I am able to see field names under _mappings, but they appear to have additional strings such as .properties, ignore_above, etc.:

I am not able to see any documentation in elasticsearch docs or even kibana docs around how they format their documents for presenting to end users. Any input is welcome.

Kibana is a UI, and it uses this endpoint to fetch the fields but keeps them in a separate index generally named .kibana. So, while storing the fields it transform it what format it requires. So, maybe, you can transform the mapping endpoint result, too?

yeah seems like thats going to be the solution. I have implemented something similar for myself. I was hoping to be able to use something 'official' for a solution, but I can make my own.

could you add the expected output?

The first image shows the display in kibana, the way the fields are laid out.
